# How to transform a table with factors to a table with counts (in R)?

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I am working with GSEA analyses (from `clusterProfiler` package) and want to perform leading edge analyses. For this I need to extract raw data from a `gseaResult`.

```
#FYI my code looks like this:
GSEA_GO <- gseGO(geneList=gene_list, keyType = "SYMBOL", OrgDb = org.Hs.eg.db)
View(data.frame(GSEA_GO@result))
```

```
#after extraction and data transformation, this is a reprex of what I end with:
#one letter being a gene name (included in the leading edge), and "GSx" being a gene set
GS1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f") 
GS2 <- c("b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g") 
GS3 <- c("a", "b", "c", NA,NA,NA) 
GS4 <- c("a", "d", "e", "g", NA, NA) 
GS5 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", NA, NA) 
df <- data.frame(rbind(GS1, GS2, GS3, GS4, GS5))
```

[image: table1]

In order to go further, I must transform this table to another in which every column represent the presence (=1) or the absence (=0) of the gene in the gene set (ie in the row). It would looks to something like this:

[image: table2]

Of course I have hundreds of genes, and hundreds of gene set...
I don't want to do everything by hand with ifelses...
could anyone provide some clues for going to the right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you will have an easier time defining you data in "long" format and then reshaping it wider, either with `pivot_wider()` or using the package `fastDummies`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

GS1 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f") 
GS2 <- c("b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g") 
GS3 <- c("a", "b", "c", NA,NA,NA) 
GS4 <- c("a", "d", "e", "g", NA, NA) 
GS5 <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", NA, NA) 

df <- tibble(
  name = rep(c("GS1", "GS2", "GS3", "GS4", "GS5"), each = 6L),
  value = c(GS1, GS2, GS3, GS4, GS5)
)

df |> 
  filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
  fastDummies::dummy_cols("value", omit_colname_prefix = TRUE) |> 
  summarize(across(!value, sum), .by = name)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 8
#>   name      a     b     c     d     e     f     g
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 GS1       1     1     1     1     1     1     0
#> 2 GS2       0     1     1     1     1     1     1
#> 3 GS3       1     1     1     0     0     0     0
#> 4 GS4       1     0     0     1     1     0     1
#> 5 GS5       1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

An even faster way is to use `table()` to get a quick contingency table (and then convert into a dataframe if necessary):

```r
df |> 
  filter(!is.na(value)) |> 
  table() |> 
  as.data.frame.matrix()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are probably more elegant ways to do this but I would try melting and casting wide again:

```r
# create id column
df$id <- rownames(df)

# melted
df_melt <- df |>
    data.table::as.data.table() |>
    data.table::melt(id.vars = "id") |>
    na.omit()
```

```r
> head(df_melt)
    id variable value
1: GS1       X1     a
2: GS2       X1     b
3: GS3       X1     a
4: GS4       X1     a
5: GS5       X1     a
6: GS1       X2     b
```

Then you can cast wide again:

```r
# wide
df_wide <- data.table::dcast(df_melt, id ~ value)
```

```r
> df_wide
    id    a    b    c    d    e    f    g
1: GS1    a    b    c    d    e    f <NA>
2: GS2 <NA>    b    c    d    e    f    g
3: GS3    a    b    c <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
4: GS4    a <NA> <NA>    d    e <NA>    g
5: GS5    a    b    c    d <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Then you can mutate across all columns (excluding id) to be 1 if present, 0 if absent.

```r
# get letter column only
genes <- colnames(df_wide)[colnames(df_wide) != "id"]

# change all gene cols to be 1 if present, 0 if absent
df_wide[, (genes) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1)), .SDcols = genes]
```

```r
> df_wide
    id a b c d e f g
1: GS1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
2: GS2 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
3: GS3 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
4: GS4 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
5: GS5 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Where the `genes` vector is:

```
> genes
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sorry but this does not work : I replaced penultimate line by ```"genes <- colnames(df_wide)[colnames(df_wide) != "id"]``` to get the proper colnames (instead of X1, X2, X3...) but the last line does not return anything nor does it change "df_wide" df. Any clues?

Comment: @B_slash_ thanks for catching the code error! It should definitely be w/ `df_wide`. I've modified the answer to correct that and showed what the `genes` vector should be (just the letters a, b, c, etc.). `data.table` does not print when you perform an operation but if you look at it after the fact those columns should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can, first, `match` the matrix with unique genes (you probably have sth like a vector of `unique_genes`; if not, we can obtain `unique` strings from making the matrix `as.vector`, which is slower, though), then we `apply` `tabulate` row-wise.

```
> M
        e000001 e000002 e000003 e000004 e000005 e000006
GS00001 "aab"   NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
GS00002 "aaa"   "aab"   "aac"   "aad"   "aae"   NA     
GS00003 "aad"   NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
GS00004 "aaa"   NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
GS00005 "aab"   "aae"   NA      NA      NA      NA     
GS00006 "aaa"   "aab"   "aad"   "aae"   NA      NA     
> f <- \(m, u) {
+   if (missing(u)) {
+     u <- unique(as.vector(m)) |> sort()
+   }
+   m_prime <- match(m, u) |> array(dim(m), dimnames(m))
+   apply(m_prime, 1, tabulate, nbins=length(u)) |> t() |> `colnames<-`(u)
+ }
> f(M, unique_genes)
        aaa aab aac aad aae
GS00001   0   1   0   0   0
GS00002   1   1   1   1   1
GS00003   0   0   0   1   0
GS00004   1   0   0   0   0
GS00005   0   1   0   0   1
GS00006   1   1   0   1   1
```

Let's **benchmark** this on more realistic data, i.e. 150 GS and 1e4 genes.

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
+   f(ML),
+   f(ML, unique_genes_L),
+   times=3L,
+   check='identical'
+ )

$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
Unit: seconds
                  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
                 f(ML) 8.589817 8.821353 9.001428 9.052888 9.207233 9.361579     3  a 
 f(ML, unique_genes_L) 4.803981 5.250883 5.472974 5.697785 5.807471 5.917156     3   b
```

Providing the unique genes is twice as fast.

---

*Data:*

```
sim_dat <- \(n_GS, n_genes, seed=42L) {
  set.seed(seed)
  stopifnot(n_genes < 17576 + 1L)
  gene_univ <- outer(letters, letters, paste0) |> outer(letters, paste0) |> as.vector() |> sort()
  gene_univ <- gene_univ[seq_len(n_GS)]
  GS_lst <- lapply(sample.int(length(gene_univ), n_genes, replace=TRUE), \(n) 
                   sort(sample(gene_univ, n, replace=F)))
  GS_lst <- lapply(GS_lst, `length<-`, n_genes)
  do.call('rbind', GS_lst) |> 
    `dimnames<-`(list(sprintf('GS%05d', seq_along(GS_lst)), sprintf('e%06d', seq_len(n_genes))))
}

M <- sim_dat(5, 6)
unique_genes <- unique(as.vector(M)) |> sort()

ML <- sim_dat(150, 1e4)
unique_genes_L <- unique(as.vector(ML)) |> sort()
```

Comment: thanks for providing this solution! it is a bit more complicated than @dufei but would be usefull for large dataset! I indeed have 600+ pathways and 1000+ genes. You seem to be familial with GSEA/Leading edge analysis. Are you? Could you provide me some usefull ressources so I can work harder on this topic? R packages or any other litterature would be usefull!

Comment: @B_slash_ I couldn't think of a faster solution, but you have made your choice for a solution that might be less complicated but takes about ten times longer. You might delve into https://www.biostars.org/